# How do you order lists in the same way QuerySets are ordered in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model that has an ordering field under its Meta class.  When I perform a query and get back a QuerySet for the model it is in the order specified.  However if I have  instances of this model that are in a list and execute the sort method on the list the order is different from the one I want.  Is there a way to sort a list of instances of a model such that the order is equal to that specified in the model definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not automatically, but with a bit of work, yes.  You need to define a comparator function (or **cmp** method on the model class) that can compare two model instances according to the relevant attribute.  For instance:

```
class Dated(models.Model):
  ...
  created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

  class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)

  def __cmp__(self, other):
    try:
      return cmp(self.created, other.created)
    except AttributeError:
      return cmp(self.created, other)
```

Comment: +1 nice solution that keeps the sorting at the model level so it can be transparently honoured no matter where the list sorting is done.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is varying degrees of yes, with some manual requirements.  If by `list` you mean a `queryset` that has been formed by some complicated query, then, sure:

```
queryset.order_by(ClassName.Meta.ordering)
```

or

```
queryset.order_by(instance._meta.ordering)
```

or

```
queryset.order_by("fieldname") #If you like being manual
```

If you're not working with a queryset, then of course you can still sort, the same way anyone sorts complex objects in python:

- Comparators
- Specifying keys
- Decorate/Sort/Undecorate

[See the python wiki for a detailed explanation of all three.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting)

Answer (score 2):

Building on Carl's answer, you could easily add the ability to use all the ordering fields and even detect the ones that are in reverse order.

```
class Person(models.Model):
  first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  birthday = date = models.DateField()

  class Meta:
    ordering = ['last_name', 'first_name']

  def __cmp__(self, other):
    for order in self._meta.ordering:
      if order.startswith('-'):
        order = order[1:]
        mode = -1
      else:
        mode = 1
      if hasattr(self, order) and hasattr(other, order):
        result = mode * cmp(getattr(self, order), getattr(other, order))
        if result: return result
    return 0
```

Comment: Very nice. Best to put that into a subclass of `models.Model` too so you can use it throughout your models.